# Load eCharts Multiline with only one series selected by default

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have a multiline chart defined as follows:

```js
{
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
  },
  legend: {
    data: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: labels,
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      symbol: 'circle',
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series',
        blurScope: 'coordinateSystem',
      },
      step: 'end',
      name: 'A',
      data: [1, 2, 3],
    }, ...,
  ],
};
```

When clicking on a legend, it toggles the corresponding line. I would like to load this graph with one of the lines toggled "off" while displaying the others.

Does echarts support that functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
legend: {
   data: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
   selected: {
     'A': true,
     'B': true,
     'C': false,
     'D': false
   }
},
```

In your legend object, create the 'selected' object with your legend names and set whichever ones you want to show as true and the ones you don't want to show as false