# Apache Superset - certain datasets hidden by default - how?

Tags: apache-superset

Is it possible to set certain datasets as HIDDEN BY DEFAULT.
As the image below shows - two elements are hidden, one is active. I'd like to have this on page load with ability to unhide those, if needed.

[image]

Comment: Example of what I am looking for , done with ChartJS:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846177/chart-js-how-to-set-a-line-chart-dataset-as-disabled-on-load#answer-38479384

Comment: This operation(of hiding elements) in charts is currently supported manually, so I don't it is possible at the moment to make it default behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible in Superset (speaking for the current state of the main branch, which is pretty close to what upcoming version 3.0 will be).

Additional context:

1. Superset is moving away from its legacy charts based on NVD3, replacing them with equivalent charts based on Apache ECharts.  Some of the migrations will happen in 3.0, though not line charts.
2. It appears the behavior you seek is [possible in ECharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72886596/load-echarts-multiline-with-only-one-series-selected-by-default), so in theory this could become a feature in Superset.
3. For anyone looking into implementing this, that ECharts action of unselecting a legend category appears in the codebase behind the feature of double-clicking a data series to show only a single series, discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/23735).

That action in #3 might be the closest thing for now, but requires a user to double-click.